# HTML5 Camera Image XMLHttpRequest file is empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, mobile, camera

I am attempting to read the camera using HTML5 and XMLHttpRequest. I have tried a couple of things but no matter what I change I can not seem to actually send the Form Data, data through the post. So can someone tell me where I am making the error and not generating any image to save. Alternatively if you don't have to call out to a url but instead use a local function that would be awesome.

aspx file and the HTML structure.

```
<!-- CAMERA UPLOAD -->
<div class="row" runat="server" id="div_Upload" visible="false">
    <hr />
    <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="btn btn-shadow" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="fileSelected()" />
    <input type="button" name="btn_upload" value="Upload" id="btn_upload" onclick="uploadFile()" class="btn btn-shadow" />
    <div id="fileName"></div>
    <div id="fileSize"></div>
    <div id="fileType"></div>
    <div id="progressNumber"></div>
    <hr />
</div>
```

The javascript in the head of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function fileSelected() {
        var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
        alert("fileSelected : " + file.name);
        if (file) {
            var fileSize = 0;
            if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
                fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
            else
                fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

            document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
            document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
            document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
        }
    }

    function uploadFile() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]
        alert("upload File : " + file.name);
        fd.append(file.name, file);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "SaveToFile.aspx");
        xhr.send(fd);
        alert("xhr Response: " + xhr.response);
    }

    function uploadProgress(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
        }
    }

    function uploadComplete(evt) {
        /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
        alert(evt.target.responseText);
    }

    function uploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
    }

    function uploadCanceled(evt) {
        alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
    }

</script>
```

And here is the SaveToFile.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%
    HttpFileCollection files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

    for (int index = 0; index < files.Count; index++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile uploadfile = files[index];
        uploadfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\upload\\" + uploadfile.FileName);
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Upload successfully!");

%>
```

By the time I am calling the SaveToFile.aspx page there are no files sent and the file count = 0;

Any help would be greatly appreciated! And a way to keep within the same page would be awesome. I saw a reference to that in another post but when I call a local function, I get a 404 error.

Comment: Anyone? This problem has been plaguing me for too long now. I play with this trying many different things and still come up with no files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With asp.net and webforms, the form information was incomplete.

I went from

```
<form>
```

on the site master page to

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This fixed all issues and several different options to get data from client side, fixed themselves once I made the change.

With a master page I don't know of a different way to resolve this but this works with the site master.